# Prove or disprove: A = lim$_{n\to\infty}b_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

The question is:

Let $a_n$ be a convergent sequence with A = lim$_{n\to\infty}a_n$. Suppose,  $f : N \to N$ is a one-to-one correspondence of naturals. Define a new sequence $b_n = a_{f(n)}$. Prove or disprove: $A = lim_{n\to\infty}b_n$

I am having a hard time trying to find a counter example.

Help would be much apprecieated.

Comment: You are having a hard time finding a counterexample because it does not exist.

Comment: For any $N$ can you find $M$ such that $f(M)>N$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Bbb N$ be the set of natural numbers.

For $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\ge N\implies |a_n-A|<\epsilon$.  Let $M=\max\{f(n):1\le N-1\}$. So, if $n\ge M$, then $f(n)\ge N$. Therefore, $|b_a-A|=|a_{f(n)}-A|<\epsilon$.